# c# to javascript combine/merge arrays of datetime and int null default

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, dictionary

I've been searching around the web and couldn't find anything specific to what I'm looking for, so I created a new question.

I am working on MVC5. I need to populate a google chart datatable for the chart.

I have 3 lists of Test classes stored in a c# dictionary in the model of one of my views:

```
public class ThisClassIsTheViewModel
{
    //Some Properties here
    //...
    public Dictionary<string, List<Test>> TestHistory { get; set; }
    //I have the constructors here
    //...
}    

public class Test
{   //Some Properties here
    //...
    public System.DateTime DateOfTest { get; set; }

    private int _timeTaken;
    public float TimeTaken
    {
        get { return _timeTaken / 1000f; }
        set { _timeTaken = (int)value; }
    }
    //I have the constructors here
    //...
}
```

The string key in TestHistory represents the test type. There are 3 test types in total, that's why I mentioned 3 lists of Test classes above, but this number could change.

I managed to populate the datatable with 1)the date from the first list of Tests 2)and the TimeTaken property from the 2.1)first, 2.2)second and 2.3)third series of tests, creating a graph with 3 lines (one for each test).

[image: this is the graph i managed to create]

This is fine because in most cases the three type of tests are run one after the other in a couple of seconds, and the DateofTest property is stripped out of the seconds information. But I would like to make this better.

This is the Javascript I currently use to populate the chart:

```
// Create the data table.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

//Get testTypes from model
var testTypeNames = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.TestHistory));

//Add a column for the x-axis
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time of Day');
//Start a counter for the number of columns
var colNum = 1;
//Add a column for each test type (will be considered as a different line)
for (var testTypeName in testTypeNames) {
    data.addColumn('number', testTypeName.toString())
    colNum++
}

//Initialise datetime range
var minDate = new Date(2070, 1, 1);
var maxDate = new Date(1970, 1, 1);
//Initialize container for data to be passed to google datatable
var datetimeList = new Array();
var date, timeTaken;

//Get data from model to container created above (datetimeList)
@foreach (var item in Model.TestHistory[Model.TestHistory.Keys.ElementAt(0)])
{
    <text>
        //First testType
        //Get date from model
        var dateSplit = '@item.DateOfTest.ToString().Split(' ')[0]';
        var timeSplit = '@item.DateOfTest.ToString().Split(' ')[1]';
        date = new Date()
        date.setFullYear(dateSplit.split('/')[2]);
        date.setMonth(dateSplit.split('/')[1]-1);
        date.setDate(dateSplit.split('/')[0]);
        date.setHours(timeSplit.split(':')[0])
        date.setMinutes(timeSplit.split(':')[1])
        date.setSeconds(timeSplit.split(':')[2])
        //Update min/max date for graph
        if (minDate > date)
            minDate = date
        if (maxDate < date)
            maxDate = date
        //Set timetaken
        timeTaken = parseInt(@item.TimeTaken)
        //Push data to array
        datetimeList.push([date, timeTaken])
    </text>
}
@for (int i=1; i < @Model.TestHistory.Keys.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.TestHistory[Model.TestHistory.Keys.ElementAt(i)].Select((value, index) => new { index, value }))
    {
        <text>
            //Other testType
            //Get date from model
            var dateSplit = '@item.value.DateOfTest.ToString().Split(' ')[0]';
            var timeSplit = '@item.value.DateOfTest.ToString().Split(' ')[1]';
            var date = new Date()
            date.setFullYear(dateSplit.split('/')[2]);
            date.setMonth(dateSplit.split('/')[1]-1);
            date.setDate(dateSplit.split('/')[0]);
            date.setHours(timeSplit.split(':')[0])
            date.setMinutes(timeSplit.split(':')[1])
            date.setSeconds(timeSplit.split(':')[2])
            //Update min/max date for graph
            if (minDate > date)
                minDate = date
            if (maxDate < date)
                maxDate = date
            //Set timetaken
            var timeTaken = parseInt(@item.value.TimeTaken);
            datetimeList[@item.index].push(timeTaken);
        </text>
    }
}

//Pass data from container (datetimeList) to google datatable
datetimeList.forEach
(
    function myFunction(value)
    {
        //Initialize datarow with empty values and correct size (colNum)
        var datarow = new Array(colNum);
        for (var i=0; i < datarow.length; i++) 
        {
            datarow[i] = null;
            datarow[i] = value[i];
        }
        data.addRows( [datarow] );
    }
)
```

Ideally, I would like to create 3 (this could change) javascript arrays (DateofTest, TimeTaken) and combine them, using null values where there is nothing to insert (meaning that one series might have a value for 6.30pm for example, but another series wont). I already do something similar to combine list with different number of Tests as you can see in the script below.

I basically need an idea for some code that takes three lists of clases, extracts the value of two properties from each class of each list, and creates a new array combining the results from each list using null when I cannot insert a value.

The three arrays would look like this:

```
[
    [DateofTest1, Timetaken1, null, null],
    [DateofTest1, Timetaken1, null, null],
    [...],
    [DateofTest1, Timetaken1, null, null],
]

[
    [DateofTest2, null, Timetaken2, null],
    [DateofTest2, null, Timetaken2, null],
    [...],
    [DateofTest2, null, Timetaken2, null],
]

[
    [DateofTest3, null, null, Timetaken3],
    [DateofTest3, null, null, Timetaken3],
    [...],
    [DateofTest2, null, null, Timetaken3],
]
```

The array I need to build would look more or less like this:

```
[
    [DateofTest1, Timetaken1, null, null],
    [DateofTest2, null, Timetaken2, null],
    [DateofTest3, null, null, Timetaken3],

    [DateofTest1, Timetaken1, Timetaken2, null],
    [DateofTest2, null, Timetaken2, Timetaken3],
    [DateofTest3, Timetaken1, null, Timetaken3],

    [...],

    [DateofTest1, Timetaken1, Timetaken2, Timetaken3],
    [DateofTest2, Timetaken1, Timetaken2, Timetaken3],
    [DateofTest3, Timetaken1, Timetaken2, Timetaken3],
]
```

Any suggestion on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: @StephenMuecke well, I was unclear but you understood it right :D just kidding, I'll edit the questionandalso add some data sample.

Comment: @StephenMuecke still not clear, but you keep on understanding it right.. :D I have edited the question again giving examples of how the individual arrays should be, and giving different examples of possible rows of the final array.

Comment: @StephenMuecke also, could you expand a bit more on the point you made about moving most of the code onto the controller? I currently have the Model defined in a Data folder in my project. The code you see is from the View. The view is "accessed" through a controller that populates the model (using a stored procedure from a DB)

Comment: The model does reflect what I need in the class indeed, you problaly think differently because I haven't really told you what I display in the view. The structure of my model is defined in the question body. You don't really need to see the other variables in the Test class. The dictionary "TestHistory" is one of the properties of the Model of the view.